# Python selenium listen to http request s

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if there is a way to listen for http requests in selenium. By this I mean if you open the chrome inspect element in the network tab you can see all requests from that webpage. I would like to know if in python selenium you could set a listener or a callback to those requests?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not using Selenium functions or methods for this object. actually the `wireshark` software is the best choice for you.

[download link](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)